# Boot Custom ISO on Remote Dedicated Server

Tags: boot, dedicated-server, iso

My telephony service has given me an ISO so that I can host my own PBX server.

Say I have a dedicated server that I can SSH into at Rackspace. How would I get this dedicated box to load my ISO and boot with it so that it can install the image and software, etc?

**Additional context:**

We're using [Switchvox](http://www.switchvox.com/), which is an Asterisk-based PBX solution. However, unlike other Asterisk installs where you can just boot up a linux image and download and compile/install Asterisk, Switchvox provides an iso build of the entire server that includes the OS and the PBX software pre-configured.

I have this ISO. I want to know how to load it on the remote box. That is all. This is not a troll post. Sorry if it is a dumb question.

Comment: I've added the additional info to the question.

Comment: @JoshuaMcGinnis - sorry, I was kind of mean/joking with you, that was unkind. You have two problems; a) this question doesn't have a generic answer, you need to ask rackspace - that you didn't know that (don't forget this is a site for pro sysadmins) raised a few eyebrows and b) doing what you're trying to achieve (the whole PBX) thing might not be a good idea at all when done in this manner, especially if this isn't your area of expertise - it can be very complex even when all the various parts are in the same location. So sorry again, you just seem out of your depth.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this remotely is to use some sort of server management connection, like ILO (HP), DRAC (DELL), etc.

Comment: Or if the provider offers a PXE environment that allows you to load your own ISO  - I have no idea if RackSpace does something like that, or if any hosting provider does, actually.

Comment: Potentially rackspace could offer this kind of service, it's the kind of thing you can do with a vmware-based cloud via a web front end but it's a question very specifically to ask rackspace as there's no generic answer. I'm just more than a little worried that doing this in a remove VM might not be a great idea at all, in any way.

Comment: "I'm just more than a little worried that doing this in a remove VM might not be a great idea at all, in any way." Why? Because of the something related to hosting a remote PBX or something else? I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: Yep, because of the PBX thing. Voice comms is inherently a latency-reliant application; so doing it from a VM, somewhere/anywhere in the world, with little control of the data networking available between you/it/others isn't an ideal fit for the kind of service you're using. If this was a physical server at your own site, with your own network and control of that network then it can work, you've just got so many parameters permanently outside of your control that even if you get this working there's no certainty it'll stay that way.

Comment: I don't see any issues really, it's exactly the same as installing OS/2 for example. Few people did it on the VM (for example), however it doesn't means that's impossible.

Comment: @VickVega there's 'working' and there's 'creating a rod for your own back' - these two things can be the same thing.

Comment: @Chopper3, Clearly it's impossible to cover in one single answer all the aspects of the problem. However, one needs be be aware of the options available and make his own judgment as what to implement and how.

Comment: Vick - I agree with Chopper that the plan to colocate a VoIP PBX should be really picked apart to make sure that latency won't induce problems. In one of your comments, you seem to be thinking that Chopper is saying the install will be the problem? That's not what his main point is.

Answer (score 1):

If there's no remote boot management (via PXE or an out-of-band card like a DRAC, or VMware console for VM guests), then you'd have to burn this to media and have the datacenter staff remote-hands it for you.

Seems like some insufficient planning, though - you typically want to plan out the whole process before buying a product/subscribing to a service.

Comment: "Seems like some insufficient planning" - we've been using their hosted service for quite some time. I'm merely exploring hosting it ourselves for a variety of reasons not related to this post.

But your answer is helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I was referring to a Rackspace-hosted server as the service/product, not Switchvox. If you haven't already purchased it, and this is your planning process, well then all righty then. Now that you know what to ask for, you need to ask Rackspace if they offer anything for this.